# Checked some chekbox when another checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to checked the two checkbox with id check1 and check2 when opt1 is checked , i use jquery for this, here is the following code.
    the jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#opt1').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('#raw').slideDown(400);
            $('#check1').changeAttr('checked');
            $('#check2').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('#raw').slideUp(200)
        }
    });
});
```

this is my html code

```
<dl>
                                            <dt><input id="opt1" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Raw Material">Raw Material</dt>
                                                <div id="raw" class="option" style="display:none">
                                                </br><dd><input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="lol[]" value="Add Raw Name">Add Raw Name</dd><br/>
                                                <dd><input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="lol[]" value="View Raw Materials">View Raw Materials</dd>
                                                </div>
                                            </dl>
```

Comment: what's the question, can u elaborate with fiddle

Comment: ops sorry, actually my above code doesn't work

Comment: @ForhadSikder try to put your code into a jsfiddle and show us what is not working

Comment: what is `changeAttr` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a value to the `prop()` method as well as the property to set.

```
$('#check1').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K63mF/

Comment: Well, +1 but on `uncheck` it won't uncheck the other 2

Comment: You said you wanted to check the two checkboxes when checking option 1. You never mentioned unchecking...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the 2 other checkboxes when the first checkbox is checked, you can do it this way:

[(Shown in this fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/AkF4z/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#opt1').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#check1').prop('checked', 'checked');
            $('#check2').prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            $('#check1').prop('checked', '');
            $('#check2').prop('checked', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, if you wanted to check `#check1` and `#check2` when the `#opt1` checkbox is checked, this is the way to do it. The code to un-check the checkboxes in the else was just if you needed that functionality as well. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: yes thats it but i can't understand why my code is not working

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle with the current code you have, and supply us with it. We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K63mF/3/ this is the jsfiddle link , i m really surprise that its working in the jsfiddle but its not working in my code

Comment: Hard to say, it could be because of anything else in your code. We can't help with that in this thread though, you have to ask another question to get help with that.

Comment: now i figured out actually i forgot to link the jquery1.9.1 thanks all

Comment: Perfect. Please remember to accept an answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#opt1').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {

            $('#raw').slideDown(400);

            //update code
            $('#check1').attr('checked','checked');
            $('#check2').attr('checked','checked');

        } else {
            $('#raw').slideUp(200);

            //if you want to remove check
            //$('#check1').removeAttr('checked');
            //$('#check2').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: now i figured out actually i forgot to link the jquery1.9.1 thanks all